# How does iOS change file system format during upgrade to iOS 10.3?

Tags: ios, hfs+, apfs

During upgrade to iOS 10.3, the file system format will change from HFS+ to Apple File System (APFS).

How can the process retain the user data when changing file system format (how reliable it is? sounds risky)? Is the process reversible (when I try to downgrade back to iOS 10.2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's long been possible to convert one filesystem to another on the fly - [Paragon NTFS-HFS Converter](https://www.paragon-software.com/technologies/universal-file-system-drivers/ntfs-hfs-converter/) is one of many utilities that can handle the task.

Equivalent technology could readily be applied to a new disk format - though best guess would be it is a one-way process right now & to revert you would need to wipe & start over.

I wouldn't dream of doing either without a solid, tested backup in place.